# Threadsafe singleton factory to use in Apache thrift server RPC system

Tags: c++, c++11, singleton, factory-method

My goal was to write a factory that the code did not have to be edited.  Thus I am registering my factory functions into a singleton factory. I am going to be using this code in Apache thrift server RPC system. I want to make the factory thread-safe.

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <map>
#include <memory>

namespace configNM{

class config{
   public:

     config(const std::string & filename);
     config(){};

     std::string getConfFileName()const{return _confFilename;};
   private:
      std::string _confFilename;
   protected:

};

class configColumnHeaders:public config{
   private:
   static bool registered;
   configColumnHeaders(){};
   configColumnHeaders(const std::string & filename):config(filename){std::cout << "configColumnHeaders" << std::endl;};


   protected:

   public:
   static std::unique_ptr<config> create(std::string in){
      std::cout << "creating configColumnHeaders" << std::endl;
      std::unique_ptr<configColumnHeaders> MyPtr(new configColumnHeaders(in));
      return std::move(MyPtr);
   };
};

class configColumnsNoHeaders:public config{
   private:

   configColumnsNoHeaders(){};
   configColumnsNoHeaders(const std::string & filename):config(filename){std::cout << "configColumnsNoHeaders" << std::endl;};
   static bool registered;
   protected:

   public:

   static std::unique_ptr<config> create(std::string in){
      std::unique_ptr<configColumnsNoHeaders> MyPtr(new configColumnsNoHeaders(in));
      return std::move(MyPtr);
   };

};

class configFixed:public config{
   private:
   configFixed(){};
   configFixed(const std::string & filename):config(filename){std::cout << "configFixed" << std::endl;};
   static bool registered;
   protected:
   static std::unique_ptr<config> create(std::string in){
      std::unique_ptr<configFixed> MyPtr(new configFixed(in));
      return std::move(MyPtr);
   };

   public:
};

class configFactory{
public:
  typedef std::unique_ptr<config> (*configCreateFunction)(std::string);
  std::map<std::string,configCreateFunction> registeredConfigs;

  static configFactory* instance(){
          static configFactory factory;
         return &factory;
      }

  bool registerConfig(const std::string & name,std::unique_ptr<config> (createFunction)(std::string)){
   registeredConfigs.insert(std::make_pair(name,createFunction));
   return true;
  }
  std::unique_ptr<config> createConfig(const std::string& name, std::string filename)
  {
      return registeredConfigs[name](filename);
  }


};

}

using namespace configNM;
config::config(const std::string & filename){
   _confFilename=filename;
}

bool configColumnHeaders::registered = configFactory::instance()->registerConfig("column_headers", configColumnHeaders::create);
bool configColumnsNoHeaders::registered = configFactory::instance()->registerConfig("columns_no_headers", configColumnsNoHeaders::create);
bool configFixed::registered = configFactory::instance()->registerConfig("fixed", configFixed::create);


int main(void){
   config myConfig("columnHeaders.json");

   auto myPtr = configFactory::instance()->createConfig("column_headers","parameter");
   auto myPtr2 = configFactory::instance()->createConfig("columns_no_headers","parameter");
   auto myPtr3 = configFactory::instance()->createConfig("fixed","parameter");
   return 0;
}
```

I checked out SO and it looks like the best minimal singleton that is thread-safe for C++11 is:

> ```
> class S
> {
>     public:
>         static S& getInstance()
>         {
>             static S    instance; // Guaranteed to be destroyed.
>                                   // Instantiated on first use.
>             return instance;
>         }
>     private:
>         S() {};                   // Constructor? (the {} brackets) are needed here.
>
>         // C++ 03
>         // ========
>         // Dont forget to declare these two. You want to make sure they
>         // are unacceptable otherwise you may accidentally get copies of
>         // your singleton appearing.
>         S(S const&);              // Don't Implement
>         void operator=(S const&); // Don't implement
>
>         // C++ 11
>         // =======
>         // We can use the better technique of deleting the methods
>         // we don't want.
>         S(S const&)               = delete;
>         void operator=(S const&)  = delete;
>
> };
> ```

Should I change to this?  Is this good practice for a factory to register classes like this?

Comment: It appears that the only difference here is that the code in my second codeblock posted has deleted the copy constructor and equals operator method.